# Eliminate left recursion with only e terminal

Tags: parsing, grammar, left-recursion

If there is a grammar:

```
A -> AA | e
```

where e is epsilon (the empty string) is there any way to eliminate left recursion from this grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is all of the grammar then of course you can:

```
A -> e
```

if not please provide more of your homework ;)